# WPF Enum binding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, combobox, enums

Under models in my project I have following enum:

```
public enum Status { Pending, Approved, Skipped, Denied };
```

And following Appointment class:

```
 public class Appointment
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public string Details { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public Status Status { get; set; }
    }
```

In ViewModel, I have following properties:

```
        private Appointment _nextAppointemnt;
        public List<Appointment> AppList { get; set; } 
        public Appointment NextAppointment
        {
            get {  return _nextAppointemnt; }
            set { _nextAppointemnt = value; OnPropertyChanged("NextAppointment"); }
        }
        public string[] Statuses { get; set; }
```

AppList - list of appointment fetched from database;
NextAppointment -is calculated based on current time (`NextAppointment = AppointmentService.GetNextAppoinment(AppList)`) - simply returns thw closest appointment from AppList
Statuses - names of statuses from enum Status, calculated as:

```
Statuses = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Status));
```

On my View I have a combobox - which should have all possible statuses from enum Status, so I do following binding:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Statuses}" />
```

The problem appears when I try to bind selected value of this combobox to NextAppointment.Status property.

For that purpose, I have created converter:

```
   public class EnumToStringConvertor : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            return value.ToString();
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            return (Status)Enum.Parse(typeof(Status), value.ToString(), true);
        }
    }
```

And do following binding:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Statuses}" SelectedValue="{Binding NextAppointment.Status, Converter={StaticResource EnumConverter}}"/>
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work (selected value of combobox is empty).

But if in the ViewMode I create a separate property assign NextAppointment.Status to it and bind it to SelectedValue of combobox - all work as a magic:

```
public Status NextAppointmentStatus { get; set; }
NextAppointmentStatus = NextAppointment.Status;

 <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Statuses}" SelectedValue="{Binding NextAppointmentStatus, Converter={StaticResource EnumConverter}}"/>
```

I cannot understand why NextAppointment.Status binding doesn't work. Could you please help me to understand?

Comment: *Unfortunately, it doesn't work* - How?

Comment: Statuses are binded to the Status enum, but selected value is empty (should be NextAppointment.Status)

Answer (score 0):

The PropertyChangedEvent for "NextAppointment" triggers only, when you change the property "NextAppointment" and not for any property of "NextAppointment".

You need for the Property "Status" also a PropertyChangedEvent:

```
private Status status;
public Status Status
{
    get{return status;}
    set
    {
        if (status != value)
        {
            status = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Status");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Should I do it in Model?

Comment: If I do similar binding to TextBlock <TextBlock Text="{Binding NextAppointment.Date}"  /> - it works, NextAppointment.Date value appears. Why it has a problem with NextAppointment.Status?

Comment: Set you in your code the selected value, too? This would destroy the binding. I tried it with my code example and it works. Or I didn't understand your problem. When it doesn't work? When you change NextAppointment or Status?